# How do I parse a YAML file in groovy?

Tags: groovy, yaml

say if you have a file called `example.yaml` which contains the following:
`- subject: maths`.

How do i grab the string after `- subject`?

I already can read the contents of the file but want to know how to grab a specific string from it.

note: i know regex may help but have never used it and would appreciate any help.

Comment: That's a pretty unusual/tricky YAML to have a top-level list with no parent object.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I am adding here the same example, but implemented with the native `YAMLSlurper` (Groovy 3.x+):

```
import groovy.yaml.YamlSlurper

def exampleYaml = '''\
---
- subject: "maths"
- subject: "chemistry"
'''

List example = new YamlSlurper().parseText(exampleYaml)
// If your source is a File
// List example = new YamlSlurper().parse("example.yaml" as File)

example.each{println it.subject}
```

**For previous versions (Original answer)**:

`snakeyaml` is a library to parse YAML files. Easy to use in groovy.

**UPDATE: changed type of the example variable to List, as the example file's top level element is a collection**

```
@Grab('org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.17')

import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml

Yaml parser = new Yaml()
List example = parser.load(("example.yaml" as File).text)

example.each{println it.subject}
```

Full documentation of `snakeyaml`:

https://bitbucket.org/snakeyaml/snakeyaml/wiki/Documentation

Comment: Getting this error:  Cannot cast objetct '[{subject=maths}]'with class 'java.util.ArrayList' to class 'java.util.Map' due to: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: java.util.Map(java.util.LinkedHashMap, java.util.LinkedHashMap)
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException:

Comment: Can you post a representative sample of your yaml file?

Comment: `--- 
- subject: maths` (new line)

Comment: I changed the type of the example variable. if your yaml was of the form x:y it would result in a map. Your yaml however has the form -x:y. This is a collection of maps

Comment: how would i go about making this recursive? say define an endpoint folder to start at and have it read all subdirectories?

Comment: this link https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml/wiki/Documentation is not accessible!!

Comment: True, I will update my answer to include an implementation with YAMLSlurper

Comment: New link: https://bitbucket.org/snakeyaml/snakeyaml/wiki/Documentation

Answer (score 20):

FWIW, the upcoming (as time of this writing) Groovy version 3.0 has direct support for yaml:
http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/api/groovy/yaml/package-summary.html with the traditional YamlSlurper / YamlBuilder combo
You could always switch to this not-yet-officially-released version.

[Edited] that version 3.0.x is now officially available, with the groovy.yaml package http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/yaml/package-summary.html

Comment: Unfortunately even a late Jenkins [v2.326](https://www.jenkins.io/changelog/#v2.326) uses Groovy [2.4.21](https://groovy-lang.org/changelogs/changelog-2.4.21.html) released more than a year ago.

Comment: @Boris yes indeed, though you can now use the built-in function `readYaml` https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readyaml-read-yaml-from-files-in-the-workspace-or-text