# How to read YAML dict in Jenkins (Groovy)

Tags: jenkins, groovy, yaml, jenkins-groovy

I have a YAML file:

```
project_name: my-project
project_version: 1.0
scan_path: 
    javascript: Core
    dotnet: Deadbolt
    dotnet: ServiceCatalog
```

Which I am reading in Jenkins with

```
data = readYaml file: "Jenkins/config.yml
scan_path = data[scan_path]
```

however when I check the map it only ever has the last element.

Is my YAML file formatted incorrectly?

When I run "println(scan_path.size())" I just get 1, and

```
scan_path.each { k, v ->
                echo "${k}, ${v}"
```

just returns "dotnet, ServiceCatalog"

Comment: There should be 2 spaces identation, but you have 4 spaces

Answer (score 1):

The solution that ended up working for me was changing my YAML config to read like this:

```
project_name: project_name
project_version: 1.0
scan_path: 
  - application: dotnet
    path: Core
  - application: dotnet
    path: Brickburn
  - application: dotnet
    path: ServiceCatalo
```

Which I saved into a variable

```
data = readYaml file: "Jenkins/config.yml
scan_path = data[scan_path]
```

And accessed like this:

```
scan_path.each { e ->
                echo "Translating ${e.getAt('application')} application 
${e.getAt('path')}"
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that `readYaml` comes from a Plugin called Pipeline Utility Steps, it is not in Jenkins core.
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that scan_path is a map so to access its key you use scan_path.key and to access its values (in this case a list of maps) use scan_path.value.

```
scan_path.value.each { k, v ->
    echo "${k}, ${v}"
}
```

I prefer this instead:

```
scan_path.value.each { application ->
    echo "${application.key}, ${application.value}"
}
```

Note: if you use for (x in y){echo "x.key, x.value"} you may get errors
see: [Jenkins Pipeline: How do I use the sh module when traversing a map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60900302/jenkins-pipeline-how-do-i-use-the-sh-module-when-traversing-a-map)

Answer (score 0):

You can use snakeyaml library for parsing yaml files.

Similar question is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41731059/how-do-i-parse-a-yaml-file-in-groovy).

Another [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/java-snake-yaml) how you can use snakeyaml.

Comment: This is for Jenkins which doesn't play by normal rules of Groovy. In order to use SnakeYaml you will have to make it available within the classpath of Jenkins. There is a plugin for SnakeYaml that can be installed in Jenkins which will give you the library without having to put the jar file in your class path.