# Jenkins Pipeline: How do I use the sh module when traversing a map?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

My jenkins pipeline content is :

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Example Build') {
            steps {
                script {
                    repos = [
                        'a': '1',
                        'b': '2',
                        'c': '3']
                    for (i in repos) {
                        echo "${i.key}, ${i.value}"
                        sh "echo test"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I got an error on build :

```
Caused: java.io.NotSerializableException: java.util.LinkedHashMap$Entry
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:926)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.doWriteObject(BlockMarshaller.java:65)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.BlockMarshaller.writeObject(BlockMarshaller.java:56)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.MarshallerObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(MarshallerObjectOutputStream.java:50)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(RiverObjectOutputStream.java:179)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:344)
    at java.util.HashMap.internalWriteEntries(HashMap.java:1793)
    at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1363)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor176.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.JDKSpecific$SerMethods.callWriteObject(JDKSpecific.java:156)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callWriteObject(SerializableClass.java:191)
...
Finished: FAILURE
```

If repos is list, run ok.

I can't  fix the error, Hopefully someone can answer that.

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Code works for me, with and without Groovy sandbox. Which version of Jenkins are you using?

Comment: Jenkins ver. 2.176.1

Comment: Works for me on 2.204.5. Maybe you need an upgrade.

Comment: I'll try, need new jenkins deoloyment. thanks.

Comment: We had this as well, but intermittently and not specifically in an iteration, and got rid of the error happening by selecting the "Do not allow concurrent builds" option in the project settings

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42770775/how-to-define-and-iterate-over-map-in-jenkinsfile. It might help.

Comment: I upgraded jenkins to ver. 2.222.1, but still return the same error.

Comment: This worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/56554905/3957754

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try to replace `for(i in repos){...}` to `repos.each{k,v-> ...}`

```
repos.each{k,v->
    echo "${k}, ${v}"
    sh "echo test"
}
```

the problem with `for(i in repos){...}`:

This statement iterates through map entries. And each entry `i` has type of [Map.Entry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) which is not serializable.

> Pipeline tries to persist the status of all variables because each next pipenine command (`echo`, `sh`) could be theoretically executed on another jenkins node.

on other hand when using `repos.each{k,v->...}` you are iterating map with simple serializable values in your case.

Comment: I just started learning groovy, always looking for the same syntax as python: `for k,v in repos`. thank you for the anwer.

Comment: It is not working in my case. Now I am getting `java.io.NotSerializableException: java.util.ArrayList$Itr`

Comment: this question was about exact case with HashMap objet. and not about ArrayList.
better to ask own question. but before this - please read about `CPS` and `@NonCPS`: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/cps-method-mismatches/#common-problems-and-solutions

Answer (score -1):

Please try more latest version of Jenkins.

Comment: I upgraded jenkins to ver. 2.222.1, but still return the same error.